# Regex - DD-MON-YY - JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been having this issue over the last few years and i've finally had enough of it

For some reason, the below regex conistantly advises that certain months (i.e. March/May) do not have a valid date for the 31'st day (naturally however both March and May have 31 days). However i've gone over this regex time and time again, yet can't make heads or tails as to why its doing it

```
 function isdateField1(currVal) {

 if (currVal == '') return false;

//Declare Regex  
var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(-)(?:|(jan)|(feb)|(mar)|(apr)|(may)|(jun)|(jul)|(aug)|(sep)|(oct)|(nov)|(dec))(-)(\d{2})$/i;

var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern);

if (dtArray == null) return false;

var dtDay = parseInt(dtArray[1]);
var dtMonth = parseInt(dtArray[3]);
var dtYear = parseInt(dtArray[17]);

if (isNaN(dtMonth)) {
    for (var i = 4; i <= 15; i++) {
        if ((dtArray[i])) {
            dtMonth = i - 3;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) return false;
else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31) return false;
else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31) return false;
else if (dtMonth == 2) {
    var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
    if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap)) return false;
}
   return true;
}
```

I think I just need a 2nd set of eyes to go over it, I don't doubt its something small overlooked.

Thanks

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and time to learn about `let` and `const` and leave `var` behind.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Why are you introducing so many brackets in here to create all these capture groups? `(jan|feb|mar|...)` is sufficient. Use a look-up table to resolve which month that is.

Comment: I think if you split this into two parts that can be independently tested your life will be way easier. Function A *only* breaks apart the given string into date components, if it can, returning an array. Function B takes an array and validates the date.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the code which tests which of the month items in the array is non null.

You start the count from index 4 but it should be from index 3 looking at this result for a January date for example:

```
Array(17)
0  : "31-jan-23"
1  : "31"
2  : "-"
3  : "jan"
4  : undefined
5  : undefined
6  : undefined
7  : undefined
8  : undefined
9  : undefined
10  : undefined
11  : undefined
12  : undefined
13  : undefined
14  : undefined
15  : "-"
16  : "23"
```

Incidentally, you are only getting a correct result for January because you test item [15] which happens to be non-null.

```js
function isdateField1(currVal) {

  if (currVal == '') return false;

  //Declare Regex  
  var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(-)(?:|(jan)|(feb)|(mar)|(apr)|(may)|(jun)|(jul)|(aug)|(sep)|(oct)|(nov)|(dec))(-)(\d{2})$/i;

  var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern);
  if (dtArray == null) return false;

  var dtDay = parseInt(dtArray[1]);
  var dtMonth = parseInt(dtArray[3]);
  var dtYear = parseInt(dtArray[17]);
  console.log(dtArray);
  if (isNaN(dtMonth)) {
    for (var i = 3; i <= 14; i++) {
      if ((dtArray[i])) {
        dtMonth = i - 2;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) return false;
  else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31) return false;
  else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31) return false;
  else if (dtMonth == 2) {
    var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
    if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
alert('31-may-23 = ' + isdateField1('31-may-23'));
```